# Setting the gettext locale independent of system locale

Tags: php, linux, gettext

We are using gettext for translation in our PHP application. It is initialized like this:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $locale);
putenv("LANG=$locale");
putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");

bindtextdomain($domain, $pathToLocales);
textdomain($domain);
```

This works fine but it also translates error messages from the OS. Taking DNS resolution failure as an example, instead of `Name or service not known` we see `Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt` in our error logs for the German site.

I have [gisted a test case](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5805146). The script will translate a string and then provoke a `No such file or directory` error. I don't want this error to be translated.

Is there any way of configuring the gettext locale without changing error messages from the operating system? We do not want to change gettext to some other translation mechanism (arrays, xliff, you name it). We don't care for Windows and mod_php, but the solution has to work for php-fpm 5.4 and cli.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `LC_MESSAGES` what means ' for system responses (available if PHP was compiled with libintl)' I would try to ignore this option, for example `setlocale(LC_ALL ^ LC_MESSAGES, $locale)`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: LC_MESSAGES is required for gettext. If you remove that from the bitmask, the translation doesn't work. What I want is a different LC_MESSAGES for gettext and the PHP process and if that is not possible I am hoping for a solution to reset the system's LC_MESSAGES after bindtextdomain() & co. Without resetting gettext to system default.